# Regular expression to split a street address that may have optional numbers with slash or hyphen in between at the end

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I try to read a street address and split the street and the number with regex.

The adress can look like this:

```
Ebory Mebory Street 1
Eborymebory Street 23/2
Filler Filler Filler Street 1-32
```

I tried to split the the string use `split()` and then put the street name together again (if there is no digit detected in the splitted string).

This works only for the first case. I think it would be better if I use regex. The problem is that my understanding of regex is pretty limited.

```
adress = "Ebory mebory Street 23".split()
street = ""
number = ""
for item in adress:
  if(not(item.isdigit())):
     street = street + item + " "
  else:
     number = item
```

The result I get is correct but only for this case. If the address is `Eborymebory Street 23/24`, it wont work because of the slash.

So, the question is how to get the street address together with the numbers at the end of the string, bearing in mind that these numbers may be optional?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate... No the same pattern in both case.

Comment: You have not stated *how* you want to split the address. Please edit your question to provide sample input and corresponding expected output.

Comment: @Bohemian Hi, I modified the question title and body to include the details. I thought it was clear from the attempt and sample input. If you think it should stay closed, sorry to have bothered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
(.*?)\s*(\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fi5Ca2/1) and the [Regulex demo](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(.*%3F)%5Cs*(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B%2F-%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?)?` - an optional capturing group 2: 1+ digits, and then an optional sequence of `/` or `-` (`[/-]`) followed with 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Elyv81) with `re.match` (it makes the pattern match only at the beginning of a string):

```
import re
addresses = ["Ebory Mebory Street 1",
    "Eborymebory Street 23/2",
    "Filler Filler Filler Street 1-32",
    "Filler Filler Filler Street"]
for address in addresses:
    street = ""
    number = ""
    m = re.match(r"(.*?)\s*(\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?)?$", address)
    if m:
        street, number = m.groups()
        if not number:
            number = ""
        print("Address: {}\nStreet: {}\nNumber: {}".format(address, street, number))
```

Output:

```
Address: Ebory Mebory Street 1
Street: Ebory Mebory Street
Number: 1
Address: Eborymebory Street 23/2
Street: Eborymebory Street
Number: 23/2
Address: Filler Filler Filler Street 1-32
Street: Filler Filler Filler Street
Number: 1-32
Address: Filler Filler Filler Street
Street: Filler Filler Filler Street
Number:
```