# Separate street name strings with street number and letter python

Tags: python, pandas, list, join

I have a column in a pandas dataframe with street names such as

```
88                       SØNDRE VEI 54
89                     UTSIKTVEIEN 20B
92            KAARE MOURSUNDS VEG 14 A
94                      OKSVALVEIEN 19
96                  SLEMDALSVINGEN 33A
97                 GAMLESTRØMSVEIEN 59
100                JONAS LIES VEI 68 A
```

what i want is to get separate columns for the street name, street number and street letter. Is there a way using pd.apply and using join to split the street names into three columns?

Thanks!

Edit: The 20B should be splittet to a value of 20 and B separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to split a street address that may have optional numbers with slash or hyphen in between at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774903/regular-expression-to-split-a-street-address-that-may-have-optional-numbers-with)

Comment: Is 20B the number and letter or only the number?

Comment: it should be splittet to 20 and B seperate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use this regex:

```
df[1].str.extract('(\D+)\s+(\d+)\s?(.*)')
```

Output:

```
                     0   1  2
0           SØNDRE VEI  54   
1          UTSIKTVEIEN  20  B
2  KAARE MOURSUNDS VEG  14  A
3          OKSVALVEIEN  19   
4       SLEMDALSVINGEN  33  A
5     GAMLESTRØMSVEIEN  59   
6       JONAS LIES VEI  68  A
```